# What could've been a 'correct question' for the following answer about how the UK, US, Japan & Australia are allies?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Re this [When and how did X and Y become allies?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/when-and-how-did-x-and-y-become-allies)

Essentially, I wanted to ask the relationship US, UK, Australia & Japan, Bobby Fischer's ['allies of evil' to counter George Bush Jr's 'axis of evil'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARNSi0cPu60) Iran, Iraq & North Korea.

Actually, if you check the full press conference, then you'll find out a reporter asks Bobby Fischer right after why exactly Bobby considers US, UK, Australia, Japan evil. Bobby answers that they invaded Iraq & Afghanistan.

I think somehow there should be some kind of question where the answer could be

> Actually a reporter asks Bobby Fischer right after why exactly Bobby considers US, UK, Australia, Japan evil. Bobby answers that they invaded Iraq & Afghanistan. ( blah blah blah ) George Bush Jr said 'axis of evil' in 2002 after Al-Qaeda attacked on 2001Sep11. Then Bush Jr invaded Iraq in 2003. This connects because ( blah blah blah ). Then Bobby was arrested in [Japan in 2004](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzuv_72ybAs) in relation to Bobby's indictment by Bush Sr back in [1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%E2%80%93Spassky_(1992_match)). Etc. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-diamond, personal answer.

Two issues were raised in comments, and I think the answer to your meta-question is that the original question should have addressed these issues.

## Define allies.

1. If you want to know the date when each country became an American ally, most of them are expressed in formal treaties which are simple to find.
2. If you want to know the date when the four nations allied together jointly, that might be slightly more difficult.
3. Alternatively (and quite frankly most probably), is the definition derived from the next issue?

## What is the **Allies of Evil**?

1. Is there any record of this term being applied to these four nations prior to Fischer's use of the term?  Is the question about something that is recognized to exist by the community, or is it the interpretation of one person's opinion.  This is a tougher issue to address, but it could have been done.  If "allies of evil" is a term coined by Fischer, then historical sources and methods are only going to be able to offer a partial, trivial answer  (When Fischer coined the term.)